# R - Add columns to dataframes in list by looping through elements in a vector

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

I am working with several datasets that measure the same variables over many years. I am trying to add a year variable to each dataset, but more generally I want to loop through elements in a vector and add each as a new column in a list of dataframes. This question was similar to mine but I want to iteratively add each element in a vector to the corresponding dataframe as a new column:
[R - New variables over several data frames in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523158/r-new-variables-over-several-data-frames-in-a-loop?rq=1)

Here's sample data:

```
year <- c(1:3)
data1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1:5))
data2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(11:15))
data3 <- data.frame(var1 = c(21:25))
data_list <- list(data1 = data1, data2 = data2, data3 = data3)
```

I want to do this but think there's probably some way to loop (or lapply) that I haven't been able to figure out yet:

```
data1$year <- year[1]
data2$year <- year[2]
data3$year <- year[3]
```

Since I have many years and datasets to work with, it'd be great to have a more efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: I don't recommend it, but... `lapply(year, function(x){data_list[[x]][["year"]] <<- x})`

Comment: `Map(function(x, y){data.frame(x, year = y)}, data_list, year)`?

Comment: @alistaire - I like the concept - `Map(cbind, data_list, year=year)` should do it.

Comment: @thelatemail Interesting, I've never passed named arguments to `...` in `...`, but now that I see it, it's so obvious!

Comment: @thelatemail that resolved it! Thanks so much. I've never used the Map() function so will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The full answer based on @@thelatemail comment:

The function `Map(cbind, data_list, year=year)` should do the job. Step by step:

- `Map` function indicates a loop through elements in a list
- `cbind` attaches newly created column
- `year = years` creates new column named `year` based on elements in a vector `years`

---

Having your dummy example:

```
# vector of values you wish to add
years <- c(1:3)     # changed to plural to indicate vector of values rather than single value

# make dummy list of dataframes
data1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1:5))
data2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(11:15))
data3 <- data.frame(var1 = c(21:25))
data_list <- list(data1 = data1, data2 = data2, data3 = data3)

# Loop through list of dataframes and to each dataframe add a new column
Map(cbind, data_list, year=years)
```

The output you wish:

```
$`data1`
  var1 year
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    4    1
5    5    1

$data2
  var1 year
1   11    2
2   12    2
3   13    2
4   14    2
5   15    2

$data3
  var1 year
1   21    3
2   22    3
3   23    3
4   24    3
5   25    3
```